# Why my List show a string separate the characters and showing it as list

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

My current csv file :

```
  'Date','Category','Ability' 
  '21,14,5','Sparrow','Air,land' 
  '4,5,6','Eagle','Air,Land'
  '21,14,5','Penguin','water,land'
```

my code:

```
Living_beings=[]
with open(users_read,'r') as f:
  reader=DictReader(f)
  for row in reader:
    if date.today().day in row['Date']:
         Living_beings+=row['Category']
  print(Living_beings)
```

Output ; `['S','p','a','r','r','o','w','P','e','n','g','u','i','n']`

Expected output: `[Sparrow, penguin]`

I am not sure why it was split up...Any ideas on this.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. Please read about how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your csv data looks wrong, you can't use commas as a delimiter while your data also contains commas...

Comment: @ddejohn......We converted an Excel file into csv...So we didnt own that file....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Living_beings.append(row['Category'])` instead.

My suspicion is the original code is treating `row['Category']` as a list of individual characters so it can combine the lists.

Answer (score 3):

The line `Living_beings+=row['Category']` treats the contents of `row['Category']` as a list of characters (because it is a string), and extends the `Living_beings` list with the `row['Category']` list of characters.

Instead, you should use:

```py
Living_beings.append(row['Category'])
```